# How do I adapt Spymecached to net.sf.jsr107cache.Cache?

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached, jsr107

I need to write a new implementation against [`net.sf.jsr107cache.Cache`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jsr107cache/jsr107cache/1.1/net/sf/jsr107cache/Cache.java) using the Java  `net.spy.memcached` package (for Redis Cloud Memcached). The package does not include an implementation this interface. 
I can of course  write an adapter and implement `Cache` myself, but there are some differences in functionality

- `Object` keys, not just `String` keys, in `Cache` but not in Spy
- `clear()`
- `putAll()`
- `size()`

Given that both memcached and JSR-107 are standards -- there a standard way to adapt Spy to JSR-107?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

- Spymemcached is incompatible with JSR 107
- Only String keys are possible.
- `clear()` is implemented with `flush()`
- `putAll()` may  be implemented witha  loop.
- `size()` is not available.